# Call a function located in Service from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

So i have this Service, and everything is working, the only thing i was wondering about is if there was another way for calling my function `getWord(String w)`, from service.

I have a user text `input`, and this input is sent to the service, where `getWord(String w)` is run.

**ListActivity.java - (It's my MainActivity)**

```java
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Saving user's input in search field
                input = String.valueOf(editSearch.getText());

                //Checking if input is valid (not empty and only alphabet characters)
                if (!input.equals("") && (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
                    //Sending input to request
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("SearchForWord", input);
                    startService(serviceIntent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.input_invalid_message_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

And in the service(WordLeanerService.java) i do the following

```java
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String Checker;
        if ((Checker = intent.getStringExtra("SearchForWord")) != null ) {
            getWord(Checker); //this activates the service function
        }
return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

The reason why i ask, is because I think it's a bit stupid to start the service each time i need to run this function? Can i use the bind I made in my `ListActivity`(MainActivity)?

I also have these in my onCreate() --> ListActivity (NOTE: the button is also in the OnCreate..)
Can i use this for somthing?

```java
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
startService(new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class).putExtra("inputExtra", s1));
setupConnectionToWLservice();
}
private void setupConnectionToWLservice(){
        WLConn = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                bindService(new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class),WLConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                //ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
                WLService = ((WordLeanerService.ServiceBinder)service).getService();
                //TODO: probably a good place to update UI after data loading
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                //ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
                WLService = null;
            }
        };
    }
```

**So my question is:** Can i call the `getWord(String w)` function another way, so i dont have to call `StartService` each time i need to run it?

Comment: What that getWord() method will do. Why it was in service?

Comment: It's my API call to the website https://owlbot.info/, so what is basically do it call the website and receive information about the animal the user entered.

Comment: Yes like @Magudesh said what does the function do. Can you put the function in some common util class which can reused by the `Service` or the `Activity`

Comment: Why are you doing that API call in service. You can use separate thread in activity itself right

Comment: I did it because i was told the API part had to be run from the service, and after recieving data sent it to the `ListActivity`.